# How to make TextFormField text on validate appear below the TextFormField line

Tags: dart, flutter

here is the current situation I'm facing as I would like the red text to appear just below the line instead of above as it looks kinda ugly like this:

[image]

```dart
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
                    width: 0.5,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField( // LOGIN SCREEN EMAIL
                    maxLines: 1,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    autofocus: false,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: LOGIN_SCREEN_EMAIL_HINT,
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? LOGIN_SCREEN_EMAIL_WARNING : null,
                    onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, the line is not text field's line. It is container bottom border. Try to remove container bottom border and use TextFromField border line like this

```
TextFormField(
  ...
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 0.5)
    )
  ),
  ...
)
```